# HttpRequestMessage changes cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a request with a header where the cookie value contains a `+`, when I try to get the cookie value the plus sign is changed to a space.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var cookieValue = "YmFkIGVuY29kaW5nLi4uLi4u5vjlkYXNkZmFzZGZkc2Z+mc0";
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", string.Format("test={0};", cookieValue));

        var testCookie = requestMessage.Headers.GetCookies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cookies)
            .Single(x => x.Name == "test");

        Assert.Equal(cookieValue, testCookie.Value);
    }
```

The value returned is `YmFkIGVuY29kaW5nLi4uLi4u5vjlkYXNkZmFzZGZkc2Z mc0`, notice that the `+` has been replaced with a . Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
At worst it appears to be a bug, at best it is inconsistent as it depends on what you use to retrieve the cookie. I don't think that .NET should be decoding the cookie.

Cookie retrieved from `System.Web.UI.Page.Request.Cookies` in an aspx page.

```
"yCYq2a+J2CT2f/USHN2JudhvV2gJi4yyixkskWlOV4FmhptCtBXWUIV5n4tvO/OVUJhyWj8ZpEItLPSHSMhvw7vr+EzEGW9wlQ5FPSlHgGIG/5Qi"
```

Cookie retrieved from `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.Headers.GetCookies()` in a web API.

```
"yCYq2a J2CT2f/USHN2JudhvV2gJi4yyixkskWlOV4FmhptCtBXWUIV5n4tvO/OVUJhyWj8ZpEItLPSHSMhvw7vr EzEGW9wlQ5FPSlHgGIG/5Qi"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` is an encoding for the space character within urlencoding, so that is why it is being replaced by a .  If you replace your line

```
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", string.Format("test={0};", cookieValue));
```

with

```
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", string.Format("test={0};", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieValue)));
```

your tests should now pass.  This url encodes the string into the header, encoding reserved characters like the plus sign.

Comment: That is correct. But `+` is a legal cookie value character and not something that should be url decoded and the problem come from the fact that we already have existing cookies that contains `+` as their value.